# make a small change to a large Blazor App

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

This is a followup to a similar question I had but this time with a working example below. This app re-renders/re-calculates the entire app--even though only a tiny portion needs updating.

Open up the console to see the results.  The goal is reduce the number of times `"Monstor.Build..."` is printed.

```
@page "/monstor"

@functions {
    static int redraw = 0;
    static bool doWork = true;
    string status = "--";

    void HandleEvent(string anEvent) {
        status = anEvent; // updates every 2 seconds
        StateHasChanged(); // renders MonstrouslyDeepApp--every 2 seconds!
    }

    async Task work() { // simulate external events
        if (doWork) {
            doWork = false;
            while (true) {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                HandleEvent(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnInit() {
        work();
    }
    void Also_do_monstrous_business_calculations(int x) {
        System.Console.WriteLine("   Calculating...");
    }
}

@{
    Also_do_monstrous_business_calculations(42);
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="toolbar row bg-light">
        <span style="width:100%;text-align:right"> Status: @status </span>
    </div>
    <div class="main-app row jumbotron">
        <h1>I am Monstor App # @redraw. Fear me!</h1>
        @*<MonstrouslyDeepApp M="@ModelRoot" />*@
        @{
            System.Console.WriteLine($"   Monster.Build #{redraw}");
            redraw++;
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should avoid doing heavy calculation within views. Try to calculate it first and then keep the result around as state that you can reuse for multiple renderings.

Comment: You still haven't made clear why you need this very strange setup. Or why the 'status' cannot move to its own Component. Why do you run that method outside of `@functions { }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to my problem.  It works but it's kinda convoluted, I hope someone finds a better way...

Basically I wrap the area to be updated-in-isolation with a `<Updatable>`:

```
<div class="main">
    <Updatable Event="@statusEvent">
        <div class="toolbar row bg-light">
            <span style="width:100%;text-align:right"> Status: @status </span>
        </div>
    </Updatable>
      :
</div>
```

You define & use `statusEvent` like so:

```
@functions {
      :
    string status = "--";
    UpdateEvent statusEvent = new UpdateEvent();

    void HandleEvent(string anEvent) {
        status = anEvent; // updates every 2 seconds
        //StateHasChanged(); // renders MonstrouslyDeepApp--every second!
        statusEvent.StateChanged(); // only renders status area--every second
    }
      :
}
```

In Updatable.razor:

```
@page "/Updatable"

@functions {
    [Parameter] UpdateEvent Event { get; set; }
    [Parameter] RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit() {
        Event.OnChange += (s, e) => {
            StateHasChanged();
        };
    }
}

@ChildContent
```

And finally UpdateEvent is simply an Event wrapper:

```
    public class UpdateEvent {
        public event EventHandler OnChange;
        public void StateChanged() { OnChange?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
    }
```